# I couldn't send photo to telegram api (400_Bad_Request)

Tags: php, bots, telegram, vps

I am using `irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk` libs for telegram bot. I have one problem: I didn't send a photo may bot. Why I don't understand. Here my code:

```
$chat_id = $chat->getId();

    $params = [
        'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        // 'photo' => InputFile::create($url, "new_naushnik.jpg"),
        'photo' => "https://bot.ebots.uz/public/naushnik.jpg",
        // 'photo' => $url
        // 'caption' => 'Some caption',
        // 'parse_mode' => "HTML",
    ];

    CCommon::cLog($params);

    try {
        $response = $telegram->sendPhoto($params);
        CCommon::cLog($response);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        CCommon::cLog($e->getMessage());
    }
```

This `$response` telegram API:

```
{"<html>\r\n<head><title>400_Bad_Request<\/title><\/head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>400_Bad_Request<\/h1><\/center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx\/1_16_1<\/center>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>\r\n":""}
```

pls, help me

**EDIT**: `sendPhoto, sendDocument, send...` not worked

Comment: Double check if you have correct value in $chat_id (string or integer)
https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/v2.0/reference#sendphoto

Comment: @SergeAndriichuk absolute correct value, because $chat_id replaced own chat_id, but it didn't work

Comment: You can add debug option (RequestOptions::DEBUG => true) to HTTP client and see full request/response messages
https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/develop/src/HttpClients/GuzzleHttpClient.php#L114
https://github.com/andriichuk/php-curl-cookbook#debug-request

Comment: @SergeAndriichuk I have found answer it is below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer. it is `sudo apt-get install php-curl`